# How can I sum two rows from two different tables?

Tags: sql, sum

I am facing a problem in sql query. I am attaching the Schema.[image]

The thing i want is. I want to generate a query that will produce result like below.

```
=======================================================================================
 showroom_id  |  total_salary  | total_expense |  total_sold | balance
=======================================================================================
|     1       |    2000        |   8000        |   30000     | 20000
=======================================================================================
|     2       |    1000        |   4000        |   25000     | 20000
=======================================================================================
|     3       |    3000        |   7000        |   30000     | 20000
====================================================================================
```

I want to group by showroom id and sum the expense amount , staff salary, item's price and show them in each individual row. Then another column balance will show `total_sold -( total_expanse + total_salary)`. How can I do the query?

Comment: Please provide the code you've attempted and what went wrong.

Comment: Also please tag your DBMS.

Comment: have you tried anything? Please read this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Basically what i did is, selecting sum(coloumn) with group by showroom_id with joining three tables (showroom, staff_salary and expense) which resulted a single row appearing multiple times and apparently I got double of the answer I am expecting. So , Roman Pekar's Idea worked for me.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Outer join and nested select query with group by was the thing I needed.

Comment: please tag your RDBMS

Comment: @RomanPekar Please read all comments before posting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    s.id as showroom_id,
    sal.amount as total_salary,
    exp.amount as total_expense
    -- not sure where to get total_sold amount?
from showroom as s
    left outer join (
        select sum(t.amount) as salary, t.showroom_id
        from staff_salary as t
        group by t.showroom_id
   ) as sal on sal.showroom_id = s.id
    left outer join (
        select sum(t.amount) as salary, t.showroom_id
        from expense as t
        group by t.showroom_id
   ) as exp on exp.showroom_id = s.id
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Your Idea worked. :)

I got my answer by doing.......................................................


select e.expenses , s.salaries , showroom.id as showroomid from (select expense.*, sum(amount) as expenses from expense group by expense.showroom_id) e 
left outer join showroom on e.showroom_id = showroom.id 
left outer join (select *, sum(salary.amount) as salaries from salary group by salary.showroom_id )s on s.showroom_id = showroom.id

[note : i changed the tablenames]